# ionic 4 getting an error in app.module.ts page, import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image] when i hoover on error am getting Parsing error: Cannot read file <**'e:\simmongrim\spotify\tsconfig.json'.eslint.**> colud anyone please help me. have been struck with this error for more than a week did not get any solution. please please anyone help me. thanks in advance..

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use reactive forms, then it might be that you are missing ReactFormsModule in your imports.

Comment: its just a blank app and i haven't added any forms simplt it is getting an error.

Comment: Can you post the code from app.module.ts since it looks like the error is located there.

Comment: mikkel i have added my code above please help me?

Comment: Maybe it is your tsconfig.json file which causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `tsconfig.json` file exist at the root of your app (`e:\simmongrim\spotify\tsconfig.json`)? If not, you will want to add that file. [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration) has a TypeScript configuration page that may also help you with properties to add to that file.